# IValueConverter - Get source object at Convert method

Tags: .net, ivalueconverter

Is there a way to get the source object in the Convert method of a Converter class. I know how to get the converted property but is it possible to get the object that the property belongs to?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Darin says, this isn't possible with an IValueConverter. You can't assign it to ConverterParameter either because it's not a dependency property. However it is possible if you go down the route of MultiBinding. That way, you can actually bind to your calling object, and the IMultiValueConverter will receive the object in the binding value array. This MSDN thread has a quick example...

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/9f3e4f6d-20d2-4c13-90a2-7c157ed4f8c3/

Comment: Thanks Tom. I can get the object with MultiValueConverter as you said.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. This information is never passed to the [Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.convert.aspx) method. Also a value converter works by specifying a source and destination type. If you need to access the parent object define the source type one level higher in the object hierarchy.